# ForEach is faster than my Observable returns values

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

I have the following code:

```
evaluateLocations() {
  const locs = this.currentTour.locIds;
  let lastLoc = null;
  locs.forEach(loc => {
    console.log(lastLoc, loc);
    if (lastLoc !== null) {
      console.log('if durch', lastLoc, loc);
      this.afDb.list('routes', {
        query: {
          orderByChild: 'idStart',
          equalTo: loc
        }
      }).switchMap(items => {
        console.log('switchMap starts', lastLoc, loc); //here the output is always lastLoc = loc while it shouldn't be that
        const filtered = items.filter(item => item.idEnd === lastLoc);
        const route = filtered[0];
        return Observable.of(route);
      }).subscribe();
    }
    lastLoc = loc;
  });
}
```

Now, at the point the `switchMap` comes into play, the `forEach` loop seems to have run through so the filtering is always done wrong.

My logic is:
I want to loop through an array of ids. Then I call the database that gets all the entries where the starting point is `locs[n]`. I then want to filter for `locs[n+1]` and it will return one result.

In theory this should work, but given that I query from a `Firebase` database, the Observable has a time lag in there and I cannot get the values quickly enough. Another thing I suspect and what I read about is the fact that `Observables` might be cancelled if another one is started before the current one is finished. But when I run my code this does not seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to work that list sequentially, you need to wait for the operation of the `Observable` to finish. An idiomatic way to do that [seems to be](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md) converting the `Observable` to a `Promise` and to `await` that:

Applying that to your code:

```ts
async evaluateLocations() { // <-- make method async, so we can use await
  const locs = this.currentTour.locIds;
  let lastLoc = null;
  for (let locKey in locs) { // <-- use regular for-in loop
    let loc = locs[locKey];
    console.log(lastLoc, loc);
    if (lastLoc !== null) {
      console.log('if durch', lastLoc, loc);
      await this.afDb.list('routes', { // <-- use await here
        query: {
          orderByChild: 'idStart',
          equalTo: loc
        }
      }).switchMap(items => {
        console.log('switchMap starts', lastLoc, loc); //here the output is always lastLoc = loc while it shouldn't be that
        const filtered = items.filter(item => item.idEnd === lastLoc);
        const route = filtered[0];
        return Observable.of(route);
      }).toPromise(); // <-- convert to Promise
    }
    lastLoc = loc;
  }
}
```

Don't forget you now need to await `evaluateLocations()` too in the calling function, if you need to do something afterwards that relies on the outcome of `evaluateLocations()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it doesn't work because it says I need a `;` in this line `await this.afDb.list`. Do I need another async for the function call inside that `FirebaseListObservable`?

Comment: Ah, the `locs.forEach(loc => {` - missed that :)
Rewrite that `foreach` to a regular `for-in` loop to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. One more thing I needed to change was to replace all `loc` with `locs[loc]` as the `for-in` loop uses keys instead of values. But thank you very much!

Comment: My JS is a bit rusty indeed, sorry! :(

Comment: Thanks again for your help, my problem does remain though. It got shifted now, my earlier excitement vanished when I tried it for more than two locations. It somehow only uses the first pair ids when calculating retrieving the data.

Comment: I outsourced the part of the `switchMap` to a function and that got the job done.